# React webpack module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack

I started a project to create a react app.
While I ran `npm start`, it shows the following error.[Error screenshot in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH84K.png)

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ushan\OneDrive\Documents\#PROJECTS\REACT\fakebook\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\ushan\OneDrive\Documents\#PROJECTS\REACT\fakebook'
ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\ushan\OneDrive\Documents\#PROJECTS\REACT\fakebook\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\ushan\OneDrive\Documents\#PROJECTS\REACT\fakebook'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Webpack is also installed in my project.
[Screen shot of webpack folder in node_modules folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmyH5.png)

This is my `package.json` file.
[Screen shot of package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhRHL.png)

When this error occurred, all react functions work properly but `hot-reload` function isn't working.
So I reloaded page manually. It works.
I want to fix this issue and `hot-reload` function.

I have tried this,

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

This doesn't fix it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)